# XML. Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource

Tags: asp.net, xml, ftp, xmlhttprequest, hex

could you please point me, what is wrong with the following Xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <align>right</align>
  <columns>3</columns>
  <rows>4</rows>
  <backgroundColor>#333333</backgroundColor>
  <circleButtonColor>#666666</circleButtonColor>
  <currentCircleButtonColor>#000000</currentCircleButtonColor>
  <textColor>#000000</textColor>
  <thumbWidth>100</thumbWidth>
  <thumbHeight>75</thumbHeight>
  <thumbPadding>10</thumbPadding>
  <thumbBorder>3</thumbBorder>
  <thumbBorderColor>#0000F1</thumbBorderColor>
  <assetWidth>600</assetWidth>
  <assetHeight>400</assetHeight>
  <showImageCaption>yes</showImageCaption>
  <showImageShadow>no</showImageShadow>
  <target>_self</target>
</root>
```

And here is the error

```
Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'http://www.example.com/xml/setup.xml'. Line 20, Positi...

</root>
```

I am sure i could use a break, but in case i don't, before i upload the specific file, i get no errors at localhost.

**UPDATE:** After checking the Xml (Hex), i noticed that the character `0x00` (NULL) was added magically, after the `</root>`

By saying Magically i mean...

The XML file is created normally at localhost. The NULL character is appended by a custom FTP class, (which is used for upload - in binary mode), OR something else that i cannot imagine..

Comment: There don't seem to be any errors with the XML itself. Perhaps it's an issue with your code?

Comment: The XML is good; maybe the parser requires a *DOCTYPE* declaration.

Comment: Did you truncate the error message?  If so, why?  The Line and Position tell you (and those trying to help you) where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least i found the source of the problem! The error had nothing to do with XML.

The problem occurred in the FTP class.

The original code was creating the extra byte (with the value of 0x00)

```
Dim fileContents(oFile.Length) As Byte
Using fr As FileStream = oFile.OpenRead
  fr.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oFile.Length))
End Using
```

and here is the revised one.

```
Dim Length As Integer = oFile.Length - 1
Dim fileContents(Length) As Byte
Using fr As FileStream = oFile.OpenRead
  fr.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oFile.Length))
End Using
```

While uploading images i faced no problem with the FTP class. But when it comes with XML files...

Comment: Actually, I bet you were adding a null to the images as well. It just didn't happen to matter.

Comment: That is true. Since the images were displayed... the Ftp class contained no errors!

Answer (score -3):

> an XML document with no DOCTYPE
>   declaration isn't valid

-- xml.com

See *Valid XML Output: Including DOCTYPE Declarations* at [XML.com](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1027), about halfway down the page.

Comment: The same paragraph points out that this is a fairly technical definition of "valid".  As long as it is well-formed it is "legal".  "Valid" in this context means that it conforms to a specified DTD.